# Delete rows using a button but not on certain rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have been putting together a spreadsheet and want to include a button to delete rows. There are some cells at the top of the sheet that are integral to the sheets function so I would like to prevent the user from being able to delete these also. Below is a sample of what I am trying to achieve with each click of the button.

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
If ActiveCell = Range("B21") Then Exit Sub Else
Selection.EntireRow.Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"
End Sub
```

I am struggling to get this to work and have had mixed success.

Comment: please describe how you want the button to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to prevent any row above Row 10 from being deleted then:

```
If ActiveCell.Row < 10 Then Exit Sub
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
Selection.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"
```

However, this doesn't account for a user selecting multiple rows, so you need to consider that also.  You could also check for `Selection.Rows.Count > 1` and exit if true.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for what I was trying to achieve. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below according to your sample (not to delete a row when `ActiveCell` is in "B21":

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"

If Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("B21")) Is Nothing Then
    ' delete the entire row (no need to use select)
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"
```